# Why am I getting the same value for clientWidth and offsetWidth when scrollbars are present?

Tags: javascript, css

https://javascript.info/task/scrollbar-width
This is one of the most frustrating issues I have had yet. The link provided shows how to get the scrollbar width by subtracting the clientWidth from the offsetWidth. Yet I get the same width for both! I have tried firefox and chrome. The browser is not zoomed in. Scrollbars are present. I tried it in another project and got the same result. Please tell me what I am missing.

```
$(".searchEvents").click(function(){
    var div = document.querySelector('.main-container');
//        let scrollWidth = div.offsetWidth - div.clientWidth;

        alert(div.offsetWidth);
        alert(div.clientWidth);
           });
```

Comment: It works fine, but the scrollbar must be the div's: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jvfog879/

Comment: Some operating systems like Mac OS X render scrollbars as overlays and therefore clientWidth = offsetWidth. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10. I don't understand why the overflow = scroll has to be specified, that just creates an additional scrollbar to the browsers. @Bhavik Kalariya answer below works by hiding the scrollbar, then removing it. Is all this really necessary? Why is this not explicitly explained anywhere on the internet? Should it have been obvious to me?

Comment: `overflow: scroll` forces the scrollbar to be _always_ visible. If you see an additional scrollbar, the scrollbar you want to measure is probably not the scrollbar of `.main-container`.

Comment: @Corylus All I wanted to do was adjust the padding to include the browser scrollbars. I had 17 pixels as the padding when scrollbars were present, but on mobile the scrollbars take up no space so I wanted the padding to be based on the actual scrollbar width. Now it seems this solution will not work for mobile if the div based scrollbar is not zero on mobile. Checking now.

Comment: When adding a scrollbar to a div on the mobile site the width is 0 px, at least in ios. Thankfully it works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

JsFiddle link : [Click me](http://jsfiddle.net/m7xb1w3u/)

```js
function getScrollbarWidth() {

  // Creating invisible container
  const outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll'; // forcing scrollbar to appear
  outer.style.msOverflowStyle = 'scrollbar'; // needed for WinJS apps
  document.body.appendChild(outer);

  // Creating inner element and placing it in the container
  const inner = document.createElement('div');
  outer.appendChild(inner);
  
  // Calculating difference between container's full width and the child width
  const scrollbarWidth = (outer.offsetWidth - inner.offsetWidth);

  // Removing temporary elements from the DOM
  outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

  return scrollbarWidth;
    
}

document.body.innerHTML = 'Scrollbar width is: ' + getScrollbarWidth() + 'px';
```

Comment: Quick question, is it necessary to create these divs just to remove them when javascript.info says "P.S. The code should work for any HTML document, do not depend on its content." I don't want to create additional containers if unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, your code clearly works. Here is my question. Why can I not simply get the widths from existing divs?

Comment: It will calculate the difference by using that virtual div. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll appreciate if you upvote and accept if it is helpful! :)